# Get part of url in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

URL may be

```
person/show/31586
```

or

```
person/show/31586#tab1
```

Is it possible to get the ID in angular way? The routing is not managed by angular. The above url loads a page and just some content on the page is managed by angular.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `$location` service parses the URL from the browser address bar and makes the URL available to your app. Because you're using regular URL path and search segments, you have to set `html5Mode` to true with `$locationProvider`.

By default, `$locationProvider` uses hashbangs, so if you don't set `html5Mode` to true, you will get an empty string when you try to fetch the URL path.

After you set `html5mode`, you can use the `$location` service to fetch the URL path, and write your own rule to process the path.

For example, assume that your full URL looks like: `http://example.com/person/show/321`

Then in `main.js` you might have:

```
angular.module("MyAPP",[],function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

function MainController($location){
    var pId = $location.path().split("/")[3]||"Unknown";    //path will be /person/show/321/, and array looks like: ["","person","show","321",""]
    console.log(pId);
}
```

And in `index.html` you might have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyAPP">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Angular test</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: In this scenario, is the only advantage to using $location dependency injection? (Seems like NG should provide some convenient API...)

Answer (score 13):

If you'd like to get the last piece of the string, you may do something like this

```
function MainController($location){
   var pId = $location.path().split(/[\s/]+/).pop();
     console.log(pId);         //321
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody else lands here seeking help related to retrieving the url in Angular. Occasionally, one might need to access the `absUrl`:

```
console.log($location.absUrl());
```

> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:3000/home
> ```